# Volley Android Error while run

Tags: android-volley

Sir Please Help Me, My Volley Error while run

This is my Logcat
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;

And This is my app gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kalasubaindonesia.kalasubaindonesiamekanik"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`enter code here`
    compile files ('libs/volley1019.jar') // i use offline volley 
}
```

How To fix it? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is connected with Multidex. Did you try to add

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

into your defaultConfig?

You can also add this in your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

More info: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: i am newbie in stackoverflow here michal hehe